# Moving menu and buttons to upper actionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

Simple question, how do I move everything from bottom actionBar to the actionBar above (right corner). What is the theme called (assuming it has to do with themes). Also how can the bottom actionBar be removed completely!

[image]

This is currently my xml-code setting the themes. **Theme.ML.ActionBar2** is the theme setting the attribute's for the actionBar:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.ML.Default" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
          <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_math</item>
          <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
          <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

     </style>

     <style name="Theme.ML.ActionBar2" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
          <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_list_topbar</item>

     </style>

     <style name="Theme.ML.Tabs" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">

          <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>  
          <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>  
          <item name="android:gravity">center</item>  
          <item name="android:listDivider">@color/transparent</item>
          <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
          <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
          <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
          <item name="android:dividerVertical">@null</item>
          <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item> 
          <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>

     </style>
     <style name="Theme.ML.Text" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
          <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_tab_indicator</item>
          <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this if you have put in your manifest within your activity declaration.

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Comment: Thx, missed that one out. Hard to see your own misstakes sometimes :=)